# Streaming IMU data over BLE using Sparkfun 6 DOF and Blend Micro

Tags: accelerometer, arduino-micro, gyroscope

I am trying to use the RedBear Blend Micro to send data captured by my SparkFun 6 DOF IMU.  I am completely lost, and if anyone has any documentation I can read, or even tutorials that work for this specific IMU, I would highly appreciate it.